# Which is correct: 'were concentrated' or 'concentrated were'?

Tags: grammar

Which of sentence fragments is correct?

1. Tests which were concentrated on ...
2. Tests which concentrated were on ...

Comment: Reiterating what J.R. said about context, more is definitely better in this case. You bring up "tests" which brings to mind a specific usage of the word "concentrated". That's fine, but "concentrated" can also refer to orange juice, paint pigments or drugs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want either one of these; I think you want:

> Tests which concentrated on...

as in:

> Tests which concentrated on the sorting module were conducted for ten days.
>
> Tests which concentrated on accuracy completed without incident.

However, it's very hard to tell for sure when you only provide such a small fragment instead of a larger context. [More details](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) will usually bring better answers.

Comment: Although JR's change to active voice is considered preferable, you could use the passive voice as you have it in your first phrase.  However, your second phrase is simply wrong; to simply "concentrate" is to concentrate your mind.  So, the "tests which concentrated were on the desk" are tests with minds of their own that were using them and were also on the desk.  Which is, of course, nonsense.  :)